# Schema for storing payment attempt records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-schema

I tried looking at similar StackOverlow posts and it seems as those questions for input about schema is valid. Also, I'm a software developer and not a DB expert by trade. So hopefully this is met well.

I'm using SQL Server, though I think this question is generic enough that it might be applicable to pretty much any SQL product as it pertains to what's the best schema for my scenario.

I'm writing a referral payment system whereby stores may credit and pay back individuals who refer customers. The entities are -

- **Referrer**: the one to be paid for referring customers,
- **Referral**: the customer that was referred
- **Referral Purchase**: The amount and date of the referral's purchase.
- **Admin**: the one doing the paying.

When determining what to pay the referrer I need to tally up all of the referral purchases that have not been credited. The sum at the time of the pay out attempt is what gets paid.

The confounding part of this whole thing is that when an Admin makes a payment, it may fail for any number of reasons (insufficient funds, the referrer gave bad PayPal information, etc.). All of this needs to be stored so that I can not only look back over past payment attempts and determine the failures and what referral purchases were involved in the failure, but also to determine which referral purchases have yet to be credited to the referrer.

The best schema I've been able to devise is the following: 
[image]

The point here is that each PaymentAttempt holds the status of the payment attempt (success/failure) and each Referral Purchase that was credited in the payment attempt has a link table which associates it with the payment attempt. One referral purchase may, then, be involved in any number of attempts to credit the referrer, with the last one being the successful attempt.

Ultimately my question comes down to this: when I need to go back and then determine how much the referrer needs to be paid at a later date, is it going to be a pain in years to come if I need to query ALL of the ReferralPurchases associated with the referrer, then join ALL of the ReferralPurchase/PaymentAttempt link tables, then join the associated PaymentAttempt status tables to find out which of the referral purchases have yet to be credited? I could see myself needing to create pretty weird queries just to find those five purchases that have yet to be credited.

Alternatively I could update the ReferralPurchase itself with a status flag, but is this considered "asking for it" in terms of data integrity (I think I could see some saying this is poor design since the state could be queried in other ways, and perhaps a bug might result in the bit being set without proper records to warrant it)? Is that bad design?

Or is there some better way to lay things out?

Answer (score 0):

Will try my best to help you out, hopefully I understand your question correctly. If I were designing the system, there would be two tables that stand out for me. The tables and their columns are.

**ReferralPurchase**

•   ReferralPurchase_Id (PK)

•   Referrer_Id (Pointing to a person table)

•   Referral _Id (Pointing to a person table)

**Payment**

•   Payment_Id (PK)

•   ReferralPurchase_Id (FK)

•   AmountToBePaid

•   StatusOfPayment

•   DateLogged

•   DatePaymentMade (Null if status is not successful)

•   Admin_Id (Pointing to a person table)

Answer (score 0):

Ben, not sure what you mean by status field. I would steer away from lifecycle status fields, but would consider a boolean. For example:

An isPaid flag on ReferralPurchase would seem like a reasonable approach. It should only be updated on a confirmed payment, and if there is a query on why it has been set, the evidence will exist in the form of history from the PaymentAttempt and link tables. This would simplify queries of outstanding payments, and pending payments would just be incomplete PaymentAttempts. There is the theoretical possibility that the history could contradict the value of the flag.

Alternatively, you could have an isSuccessful flag on the link table, which is "closer to source", if I can put it that way, in that it cannot as easily be in conflict, as it is the history itself (as long as the coder does not allow more than one row to be marked isSuccessful for a given ReferralPayment for example). Finding outstanding payments is just those ReferralPayments *where not exists* an isSuccessful link record.

Others will have different views on this. Let us know which way you go.

Comment: I think you basically got the gist of what I was getting at. Sorry for not being clearer, but I was trying to strike a balance between being long winded and detailed. 

Essentially I'm trying to solve the problem of not being, as you put it "closer to source". I can write queries to join all of the tables I mentioned and determine whether credit has been given to the referrer, but as the amount of data grows the expense of the query seems as though it would grow too. By leaps and bounds. 

I like the idea of putting the isSuccessful flag on the link table, perhaps that's a good middle road.

Comment: (I thought you were pretty clear.) A rule of thumb I use is "what most simply represents the ways things actually work". It's not always applicable but it works a a fair amount of the time. In this case, the link table is the representation of the history of an individual referral purchase (or so it seems to me), so the match between model and "real world" sounds reasonable and will probably result in a stable structure. Any workable solution will have tradeoffs between whether the rules are maintained in the DB or in code... The trick seems to be to find the right split for your situation.